# LIbrary for Zendesk or Freshdesk in React Native?

Tags: react-native, zendesk, freshdesk

Is there any library for installing Zendesk or Freshdesk in React Native ? Or if there is another provider who provide their React Native SDK ?

Comment: Try this... `react-native-zendesk-support`

Answer (score 1):

You can install this plugin:

> https://github.com/3sidedcube/react-native-zendesk

Or you can refer to WebView with this SDK for integration:

> The mobile SDKs will not work in a React Native app. You could look at building a custom experience via a webview using the Web SDK: https://api.zopim.com/web-sdk/

Comment: Why does your comment say zendesk won't integrate with react-native?